# Can not reset flutter sdk path on Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, flutter

Unfortunately, I set incorrect path for flutter sdk on Visual Studio and now I am trying to reset the path , but can't , Is it possible to reset ?
Visual Studio said :

> Warning! The 'flutter' tool you are currently running is from a
>   different Flutter repository than the one last used by this package.
>   The repository from which the 'flutter' tool is currently executing
>   will be used instead.   running Flutter tool: /home/zayniddin/flutter 
>   previous reference  :
>   /home/zayniddin/Downloads/flutter_linux_v0.7.3-beta/flutter This can
>   happen when you have multiple copies of flutter installed. Please
>   check your system path to verify that you are running the expected
>   version (run 'flutter --version' to see which flutter is on your
>   path).

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/15766 might help

Answer (score 1):

After changing the Path in your machine, 
run `flutter upgrade`. Weird but works for me