# The flutter installation is incomplete

Tags: flutter, android-studio, sdk

couldn't understand the error, anyone please help me
and what is meaning on "the flutter sdk installation is incomplete"[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpfHh.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can not reset flutter sdk path on Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52341459/can-not-reset-flutter-sdk-path-on-visual-studio)

Comment: add a home variable for flutter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I think you forgot to SET_PATH_VARIABLE"

You can refer here :

Step to Setup Flutter:
https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows

Step to SET PATH:
https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have set the path of your flutter sdk in the environment variable in your system...

Good luck ......